# Magento admin management

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

This is my scenario

The website contains many stores,

The users are super admin, store admin, customers

Now the super admin have all privileges , but the store admin can able to manage only the categories/Attributes/Products that belongs to that particular store which is assigned to that store admin.

And

Is there any tutorial available for developing extensions in magento??

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed something like that for a client, but instead of store based it's website based. Maybe it can help you.
You can download it [here](http://hotfile.com/dl/107389511/b86ba9a/RestrictedAccess-0.1.1.tar.gz.html)

Comment: Thanks david parloir... nice work.
Only issue is about catalog....
Seems to be catalogs are same for all users...
SO any suggestion to block the categories and products belongs to other website owner ?

Comment: I've edited the link with a newer version of my module, I think the categories/product problem is solved: checl it out and let me know please. Note that I've been lazy and put some stuff in this module that shouldn't be there. If you need some help to understand it, maybe you could open a thread in magento's forum and send me the link, so we don't pollute this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom permission to do this